# Trouble geting html source using .Net HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to get HTML source from this URL : "http://www.nguoiduatin.vn/con-sot-gia-ve-may-bay-cuc-hang-khong-noi-chua-cham-tran-a341336.html" using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse and got this error:
**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**
The problem is that I can get html source from many other websites except this one, and I also can normally access the webpage using browsers, bellow is a snippet of my code:

```
private string getHTMLFromURL(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteLog("getting html source from :" + url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                WriteLog("response from "+url + "is OK, start get html source");
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLog("cannot get html source from "+url+" response status code = "+ response.StatusCode);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Exception in getHTMLFromURL message = " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So, anyone please tell me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server needs  a UserAgent

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "SO/1.0";
```

That's all

Comment: Thanks, that's working. But why down vote my question, I spent half  of my day to searching  for a reason for this issue and ask a question here always my last choice.

Comment: @user2905416 Instead, I upvoted it. I wouldn't answer it if I downvoted it